# Scraping dynamic content with Selenium

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn how to scrape content from the web, and have succeeded in a previous attempt to uncover what I thought was dynamic content, but what turned out to be buried under tags that were revealed in the source code. I was able to easily get the data with Beautiful Soup and pandas thanks to the community here.

For my next challenge, I'm trying to get data off a site that is actually dynamically generated, and does not appear to be in the page source. My code is below, and while I can pull the container that holds the dynamic content, it's empty. When I view using developer tools, I can see div's with the class="event 2-2-1 row" that have some data. But every time I try to get to those tags they are not found.

Can anyone help point me down the correct path here? I've searched this forum and haven't found my answer yet.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


start_url = "https://www.tissottiming.com/Live/Index?id=0003100005010105FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF2&style=Tissot"#input("Enter the results URL: ")
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get(start_url)
content = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="container-fluid"]')
print(content)
```

This is what I get from the print statement.

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="99ca6419fd181c0bdd39797e20c739df", element="0.7688034456332402-1")>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to read [ask] and [help/on-topic] to learn how to ask a question that will attract the answers you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to parse the dynamic content  using the following code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC # available since 2.26.0

start_url = "https://www.tissottiming.com/Live/Index?id=0003100005010105FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF2&style=Tissot"#input("Enter the results URL: ")
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(start_url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='heat 2_2_1_1_1 row']")))

x = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='heat 2_2_1_1_1 row']")
print(x.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

---

```
<div class="name row"><span>HEAT 1</span></div><div class="heatsheaders row rowtitle"><div class="col-xs-05 rank">Rank</div><div class="col-xs-05 bib">Bib</div><div class="col-xs-3 longname">Name</div><div class="col-xs-1 nation">Nat</div><div class="col-xs-5 run_title"><div class="RunName col-xs-4">1ST RACE</div><div class="RunName col-xs-4">2ND RACE</div><div class="RunName col-xs-4">DECIDER</div></div><div class="col-xs-1 qualified"></div><div class="col-xs-1 points">Time</div></div><div class="rider 2_2_1_1_1_1_1 row" data-sortorder="1" data-inter-pos-x="2" data-inter-pos-y="342" data-final-pos-x="2" data-final-pos-y="342" style="transition: all 600ms ease 0ms, opacity 600ms linear; display: block; transform: translate(0px, 0px);" data-bound="true"><div class="rank col-xs-05"><span>1</span></div><div class="bib col-xs-05"><span>52</span></div><div class="longname col-xs-3"><span>GLAETZER Matthew</span><div class="teamname "><span>AUSTRALIA</span></div></div><div class="nation col-xs-1"><span><div class="img_flag">AUS<img src="/Content/images/flags/AUS.png" alt="AUS national flag"></div></span></div><div class="run_group col-xs-5"><div class="run 2_2_1_1_1_1_1_1_1 col-xs-4"><div class="time row"><span>10.218</span></div><div class="points row"><span>70,464</span></div></div><div class="run 2_2_1_1_1_1_1_1_2 col-xs-4"><div class="time row"><span>0.000</span></div><div class="points row"><span>0,000</span></div></div><div class="run 2_2_1_1_1_1_1_1_3 col-xs-4"><div class="time row"><span></span></div><div class="points row"><span></span></div></div></div><div class="qualified col-xs-1"><span>QG</span></div><div class="points col-xs-1"><span></span></div></div><div class="rider 2_2_1_1_1_1_2 row" data-sortorder="2" data-inter-pos-x="2" data-inter-pos-y="422" data-final-pos-x="2" data-final-pos-y="422" style="transition: all 600ms ease 0ms, opacity 600ms linear; display: block; transform: translate(0px, 0px);" data-bound="true"><div class="rank col-xs-05"><span>2</span></div><div class="bib col-xs-05"><span>53</span></div><div class="longname col-xs-3"><span>HART Nathan</span><div class="teamname "><span>AUSTRALIA</span></div></div><div class="nation col-xs-1"><span><div class="img_flag">AUS<img src="/Content/images/flags/AUS.png" alt="AUS national flag"></div></span></div><div class="run_group col-xs-5"><div class="run 2_2_1_1_1_1_2_1_1 col-xs-4"><div class="time row"><span>+0.028</span></div><div class="points row"><span></span></div></div><div class="run 2_2_1_1_1_1_2_1_2 col-xs-4"><div class="time row"><span>+0.000</span></div><div class="points row"><span></span></div></div><div class="run 2_2_1_1_1_1_2_1_3 col-xs-4"><div class="time row"><span></span></div><div class="points row"><span></span></div></div></div><div class="qualified col-xs-1"><span>QB</span></div><div class="points col-xs-1"><span></span></div></div>
```

Comment: That's brilliant! I've been reading comments about the wait time, and tried some of those solutions but was missing the expected conditions part. I think this will help me a lot, thank you so much.

Comment: That's great, glad it worked. If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer. Thank you!