How to use Beautiful Soup to scrap odds from Bet Explorer with Python?
I am trying to scrap for betting odds and the fixture names from the website betting explorer whose full address is https://www.betexplorer.com, I have tried to use this script to do it but it os saying that no table was found, please help me make it work
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# DEFINE THE URL to use for mining odds
URL = "https://www.betexplorer.com/"

# Send a GET request to the URL
response = requests.get(URL)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the HTML content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    # Find the table with the soccer odds
    table_matches = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'table-main-js-tablebanner-t js-tablebanner-ntb'})

    if table_matches:
        data = []
        rows = table_matches.find_all('tr')

        for row in rows:
            utils = []
            cols = row.find_all('td')
            for element in cols:
                # Clean up the text and add it to the utils list
                utils.append(element.get_text(strip=True))
            if utils:  # Only append non-empty rows
                data.append(utils)

        # Create a DataFrame with the scraped data
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Match", "Result", "1", "X", "2", "Date"])
        print(df)
    else:
        print("No table found on the page.")
else:
    print(f"Failed to retrieve data. HTTP Status code: {response.status_code}")


I expected the code to generate a Pandas Data Frame that will have the match name, odd for the home team, odd for a draw, odd for the away side to win and the date time the event is supposed to happen, because the websites uses a table to represent the fixture details, help me make it work.

I can't check the site myself now, but your selectors would be wrong: check the classes on this line and if they are correct:  soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'table-main-js-tablebanner-t js-tablebanner-ntb'}). Remember, you win some, you lose more - Australian GovernmentTM

Always and first of all, take a look at your soup to see if all the expected ingredients are in place. What do you find in soup/ response? -js- in class name indicates that content is rendered dynamically, so may use an api or selenium to mimic browser behavior. In addition - It is scrape, scraping, scraper - scrap is something completely different.

@MH, How do I do that? By inspecting the classes on that page?

yes, and specifically on the table you are targeting. Use the Dev tools in your browser (F12 is the usual short cut key to open them up)

I won't click, but if that's some online betting site, you can be sure that it gets the content you're interested in dynamically. BeautifulSoup will see empty container elements at most, the same thing what "view source" would show you, like visiting view-source:https://www.betexplorer.com/ - as suggested already, https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/ is the library what you may want to check out.

Did you use ChatGPT or another AI to generate the code in question?

@tevemadar, if the element is dynamically generated with JavaScript, does it mean the code will not find the tables and there is nothing I can do about it?

@BarrythePlatipus, I am using code from a blogging site called the Medium, didn't work so I pasted it to GPT for help first and it could not also resolve the issue

Yes, simple code with requests+bs has no chance to deal with dynamically generated content.

@tevemadar, so what choice do I have? Use a web driver?

Try read this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53599121/scraping-dynamic-content-with-selenium

The full table on that site is only completely rendered when the page is scrolled. You'll need to learn how to do that. Also, as previously suggested, you'll need to use something like selenium for such a highly dynamic site

@MH, Do I need to install the selenium web driver for python and the chromium browser for this to work?

@AnthonyKinyua If you have not already installed it, this would be a prerequisite for use - https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/install_library/

Your web page is highly dynamic and only fully rendered once the page is scrolled to its end.
Web pages that utilise JavaScript for their functionality typically do not present a fully rendered page upon first opening. That's why running GET on the page and passing the resulting HTML to BeautifulSoup often can't / won't work.
The selenium module is helpful for this but even then you'll often have to jump through some hoops to get the result you want.
This code uses the Chrome driver which you'll need to install. Selenium has emulators for other browsers so you're not restricted to Chrome.
Be patient if you decide to try running this. It's quite slow...
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeService, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time

CHROMEDRIVER = "../.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/mac64/124.0.6367.91/chromedriver-mac-arm64/chromedriver"
URL = "https://www.betexplorer.com"
options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")

data = {
    "Home": [],
    "Away": [],
    "1": [],
    "X": [],
    "2": []
}

def scroll(driver):
    height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    while True:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
        time.sleep(1) # <- traditional hack
        hnow = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        if hnow == height:
            break
        height = hnow

with webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=ChromeService(CHROMEDRIVER)) as driver:
    driver.get(URL)
    scroll(driver)
    uls = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.leagues-list")))
    for ul in uls:
        suls = WebDriverWait(ul, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.table-main__matchInfo")))
        for _sul in suls:
            home = WebDriverWait(_sul, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.table-main__participantHome")))
            away = WebDriverWait(_sul, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.table-main__participantAway")))
            data["Home"].append(home.text.strip())
            data["Away"].append(away.text.strip())
            odds = WebDriverWait(_sul, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.table-main__odds")))
            for k, o in zip("1X2", odds):
                data[k].append(float(o.text))

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

Output:
                      Home           Away      1      X      2
0               St Etienne          Rodez   1.75   3.84   4.29
1                    Genoa        Bologna   3.32   3.31   2.26
2                   Girona     Granada CF   1.23   7.07  11.36
3               Skenderbeu       Vllaznia   2.75   3.22   2.32
4                     Arba     Mostaganem   3.85   3.25   1.86
..                     ...            ...    ...    ...    ...
275                Da Nang      Dong Thap   1.20   5.66  11.07
276          TTBD Phu Dong            Hue   1.76   3.25   4.53
277    A-Leagues All Stars      Newcastle   2.72   4.39   2.05
278           Blumenthaler  Werder Bremen  45.50  28.00   1.01
279  A-Leagues All Stars W      Arsenal W   4.45   4.98   1.51

[280 rows x 5 columns]


Trying it out, Thanks for the answer. It means a lot

Should the path point to the folder containing the driver executable or the executable itself?

@AnthonyKinyua The executable

Got this error when I pointed the script to the selenium web driver _ine 115, in assert_process_still_running
raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self.path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")

_elenium-manager.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 2
_

_  raise NoSuchDriverException(msg) from err
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: Message_

Says the path supplied is not a valid file path, this is how my path looks like raise ValueError(f"The path is not a valid file: {path}")

Can I copy the executable to the root of my project's folder?

Can you edit to make the code capture the date and time an event will happen?

I need to use this data frame from a C# project, first I have to call this python script from a C# script and then save the dta to a file and then read it into a WPF grid for arbitrage betting, thanks man

@AnthonyKinyua If you can't figure out how to incorporate the date from what I've shown you I respectfully suggest that you're going to struggle with the rest of your project

I can add a new date array entry in the dictionary and then inspect how you inspect elements on the page to add them to the individual arrays in the dictionary called dayta
